# C# "Integral constant is too large" - Integer variable too large for Int32 type

Tags: c#, asp.net, integer, integer-overflow

I'm building an ASP.NET Core API that returns the periodic table and the planets in the solar system. Mainly to play with API calls, as well as data types in .NET. Building this in Visual Studio 2017.

I'm having problems with a Mass property for planets, in Kilograms. Obviously a large integer, so I've tried declaring it as a long, Ulong, Int64, and even UInt64. However, when I try to enter in a new model of a planet, and put in the mass, I get the following error:

```
struct System.Int32
Represents a 32 bit signed integer.
Integral constant is too large.
```

Here is my PlanetModel.cs where I'm describing the property:

```
...
public UInt64 Volume { get; set; } //In Kilometers
public Int64 Mass { get; set; } //In Kilograms
public float Gravity { get; set; } //In m/s^2
...
```

Yet when I move over to my PlanetDataStore.cs, here is where I'm trying to build the object with data.

```
new PlanetModel()
                {
                    Position = 1,
                    Name = "Mercury",
                    Distance = 57909050, //In Kilometers
                    Orbit = 0.240846F, //In years
                    SolarDay = 0.5F, //In Days
                    Radius = 2439, //In Kilometers
                    Volume = 60830000000, // In Kilometers
                    Mass = 330110000000000000000000, //In Kilograms
                    Gravity = 3.7F, //In m/s^2
                },
```

I get a red error squiggly over the first '3' in my Mass, with the error above. Yet when I mouse over Mass, it reads: "long PlanetMode.Mass {get; set;}
When I mouse over the equals, it reads: "struct System.Int64"

**Where is the miscommunication? Why is my property declared as a 64-bit integer, but the value stuck in 32-bit?**

Comment: //In years => //In Earth years :)

Comment: Lol yeah. The data itself wasn't going to be used at this point. This project has been experimenting on how to use objects, data, and CRUD in a .NET API environment. I'm learning it, while I have only a little experience in Java, JS, and Go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Obviously a large integer

That is by no means obvious. The mass of the earth is not an *integral* number of kilograms. You shouldn't be using any integral type for this application.  Use integers for things that are *genuinely* integers, like the number of elements in a sequence.

Use `double` for physical quantities that are accurately measured to ten-ish decimal places.  Mass, volume, length, force, and so on, should always be doubles.

This will also let you get rid of those hard-to-read numbers. Doubles let you use scientific notation because *doubles are for science*:

```
Mass = 3.3011E23,
```

Also, while we're looking at your solution, I note that for spherical planets, the volume can be computed from the radius. You might not want to store both; instead, just store one and calculate the other when you need it.

I note also that you have a single "distance" which seems to be the semi-major axis in the case of Mercury. Why are you storing only the semi-major axis, and why not call it what it is?

I note also that you have mixed up your units all over the place -- meters and kilometers, days and years, and so on. Why not keep everything in standard units?  Meters for length, seconds for time, kilograms for mass. You'll find that you make fewer silly arithmetic mistakes when you use standard units consistently.

Comment: Wouldn't double still be problematic because of floating point arithmetic inaccuracy?  Since double can only hold a 64bit number?

Comment: @maccettura: Do you honestly believe that the mass of the planet is *exactly* 330110000000000000000000 kilograms? Or do you think there might be some error in there, on the order of magnitude of 10000000000000000000 kilograms or so?  If you're willing to put up with an error of 10000000000000000000 kilograms in the initial estimate, then **why are you worried about tiny floating point errors creeping in**? The *measurement error* is probably *ten orders of magnitude larger* than the *float representation error*.  Worry about errors that matter!

Comment: I wasn't commenting critically of your answer, I saw your sizable reputation score and figured I'd ask a question.  I have never had a need to store/calculate such large numbers in the work that I do. I have a limited understanding of the problems/inaccuracies of floating point numbers so I figured I would ask as a learning opportunity.

Comment: @maccettura: Then it is a good idea that you asked the question. The reason to worry about float errors is *when you are attempting to represent exact decimal arithmetic* -- for instance, financial computations, where `$123.45` needs to be *exactly* `123.45`, and not `123.449999999999998`.  For financial computations in C# use `decimal`; it is accurate to 29 decimal places and has no representation error for decimal quantities. Use `double` for *physics* problems, where you have large magnitudes but limited precision.

Comment: I've marked your response @EricLippert because I appreciate both the answer and the advice on practice for using scientific notation as well as dealing with scientific data. I was purely looking online for basic data, because I was just looking to play with data and Web APIs. There will be no real practical use for this data once my exercise is done. However, now I know what the issues was, how to enter scientific notation, as well as better understanding of decimal types.

Comment: @as.beaulieu: For further reading, try Jon Skeet's excellent articles:  [Binary floating point and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [Decimal floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The value you have is too long for an Int64, long is also 64 bits. The largest number you can store in Int64 is (2^64 - 1)/2 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

You can store this number as floating point. If you want to store the number as a floating point you have to tell the compiler it's a floating point number.

Look up how floating point numbers are stored to get a better understanding. If you want to store it in a float you can do this 330110000000000000000000.0f

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't want to use a floating point even if you are doing calculations. If you want more precision you can use decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Long literals must be suffixed with L in C#

```
Mass = 123456789012345L
```

Though that clearly won't enable you to store a number larger than 64 bits in a long :)

Why not use a floating point type?

Comment: @kblok Answer was downvoted because OP's number is larger than the max value of an Int64/UInt64.  See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hLthNq) if you wanna see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, your number is too large to fit in the UInt64 structure.
So you'll need that BigInteger, or maybe another, wider, mutable numeric type, such as double. So your model declare the `Mass` property like this:

```
public double Mass { get; set; } //In Kilograms
```

Next, you must suffix your numeric literal with the `D`, like so:

```
Mass = 330110000000000000000000D, //In Kilograms
```

You format the number for display as usual:

```
mercury.Mass.ToString("N0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a slight problem here, the max value of an Int64/UInt64 are way less than the number you are trying to assign.

To put it in perspective:

```
330,110,000,000,000,000,000,000   //Your number
9,223,372,036,854,775,807         //Int64 Max Value
18,446,744,073,709,551,615        //UInt64 Max Value
```

Your number is simply too large for that data type.

Although I have zero experience with it, you might be able to use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) if you are using .NET 4.0 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're getting the structs and type info, but even at `Int64` that value is simply [too large](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue).  `Int64.MaxValue` is:

```
9223372036854775807
```

And you have:

```
330110000000000000000000
```

Even unsigned, that's orders of magnitude too large.  You might use [something like `BigInteger` instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).